# Node.js modules not accessible after ssh connection closed

Tags: node.js, express, ssh, passport.js

I have written my first webapp in Node.js with Express and MongoDB. As a foundation, I have used [this example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3-mongoose-multiple-files).

Everything runs smoothly when testing the server locally, and also at first when it is running on the server (which is a Ubuntu server that I connect to via SSH and use [PM2](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pm2) to keep the process running after disconnecting). The problem I have is that when disconnecting from the server, the web page that at first works like a charm throws errors in my face (see error message below).

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index"
  at Function.app.render (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:489:17)
  at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:755:7)
  at exports.index (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/routes/basic.js:4:7)
  at callbacks (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
  at param (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
  at pass (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
  at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
  at Object.router (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
  at Context.next (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
  at Context.actions.pass (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:77:8)
  at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/strategies/session.js:67:10)
  at attempt (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:243:16)
  at Passport.authenticate (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:244:7)
  at next (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
  at Passport.initialize (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/initialize.js:69:5)
  at next (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
  at next (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:313:9)
  at /home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:330:9
  at /home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:55:7
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

The node process seems to keep running, but something goes wrong when disconnecting the SSH connection. When reconnecting via SSH, everything directly start to work as usual again.

Any idéas?

EDIT:
I have managed to reduce the errors a bit by realizing that the cluster mode of PM2 doesn't work with the session used in Passport. I now start PM2 with -x and get the following errors in my browser when disconnecting the SSH and trying to reload the page:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index"
    at Function.app.render (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:489:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:755:7)
    at exports.index (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/routes/basic.js:4:7)
    at callbacks (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at Context.next (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Context.actions.pass (/home/ubuntuserver/appname/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:77:8)
```

Comment: Please post the code from this file: `/home/ubuntuserver/appname/routes/basic.js:4:7`. This is a basic filesystem layout in combination with your express settings, `app.set('views', thisPathIsVeryImportant)`. So we need to see the filesystem structure you are storing your view files in and how you are configuring express and your call to `res.render`.

Comment: Ok. My basic.js is basically just 

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
};`

I noticed that express uses `this.set('views', process.cwd() + '/views');` to set the location of the views folder in its application.js-file. When connected via SSH and logging process.cwd() i get:
`/home/ubuntuserver/` but when disconnecting SSH i get `(unreachable)`. I tried changing from process.cwd() to the actual location, but the same issue still remains. It seems like the 'views' set in application.js of Express isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly specify `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')` in your app to avoid the express default which uses `process.cwd()`. That and maybe something weird is happening with PM2 changing the process's current working directory or something odd. This is probably less about your code and more about your server environment, so tough to troubleshoot remotely. You might try using upstart instead of PM2.

Comment: I think I'm onto something. I have tried hard coding `app.set('views', '/home/<user>/<appname>/views');` in my app. When running it with both Forever and PM2, everything works as it should until I disconnect the SSH, then the views can't be found, and then when i reconnect again, things start to work again. It seems as if maybe `/home/...` isn't reachable when i disconnect the SSH. Where should I put my app on the server for it to be reachable at all times?

Comment: I have managed to get everything working when placing the app in the root (/) and then starting the Forever or PM2 process with sudo. I know this is certainly not idéal. I'm not that into setting up servers as you might notice, so any idéas on how to do it instead?

Comment: Use [an upstart script](https://github.com/focusaurus/peterlyons.com/blob/52040ac2e3c694f499c5a2f99e69250bfe9cc38a/deploy/plws-express.conf.j2). https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/404619-manage-system-startup-and-boot-processes-on-linux-with-upstart